# kinit asking for password inspite of pki configuration

Tags: kerberos, openldap, pki, sasl

Invoking kinit with the principal name to get kerberos ticket asks for password, even though I want it to authenticate with client certs which I have configured in /etc/krb5.conf. What is the way to force it skip password and only use the client cert in the AS REQ and do the pki authentication to get the kerberos ticket? I have the principal in the UPN of the kclientcert2.pem whose priv key is kclientkey2.pem and is issued by kclientca.pem. I have all of them in my /root folder. I then invoke kinit with principal name as parameter. Then I am prompted for password.

My /etc/krb5.conf realm config looks like below.

```
[realms]
        myrealm = {
                     kdc = <ldap server IP>:88
                     kdc_tcp_ports = 88
                     pkinit_eku_checking = kpServerAuth
                     pkinit_anchors = FILE:/root/kclientca.pem
                     pkinit_identities = FILE:/root/kclientcert2.pem,/root/kclientkey2.pem
                 }
```

Now I installed krb5-pkinit package in one ubuntu client. After this it did not prompt for password here. But it gave the message "kinit: KDC name mismatch while getting initial credentials". the tcpdump shows a 2nd AS-REQ with AS-REP with code 11.
On an embedded client running linux, I couldn't install the package like in ubuntu, so I copied krb5 shared libs like preauth/pkinit.so and other s0 to /usr/lib path which is the standard path of the embedded client, but it still prompts for password. @@@https://stackoverflow.com/users/696632/michael-o, we got disconnected on the other thread, can you please help to understand why the kdc name mismatch occurs on ubuntu and which library I am missing on the embedded client.

Comment: any help appreciated.